# What's the cause of a small area of an image affected by an artefact?

Tags: lens, nikon, exposure, image-quality

This presents itself as a lighter area appearing to be overlaid on the image.
1. It's only with one lens, Nikon 18-70. I have four other lenses and it does not occur with any of these. (18-55, 55-200, 100mm macro, 70-300)
2. The area is always approximately the same size and in the same position, though it does seem to become more defined as the lens stops down.
3. It occurs with both my Nikon D70 and D200 bodies.
4. This is the second lens of this model in which this occurs. I ditched the first because of this problem!
5. It appears on all images, though it is more or less noticeable depending on the underlying image colour. Most obvious on a dark background.
6. It appears on both RAW and JPG files.
Attached is just one image that shows the problem. The artefact is in the middle vertically towards the right edge of the image.
[image]
Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Do you use a filter on the lens?

Comment: Yes - a Hoya UV filter.

Comment: Try fully opening the aperture and look through the lens barrel at a white and also a black background to locate something on an internal surface of the lens. Do it with the focus racked in and out for both backgrounds. Since you've already isolated the problem to a specific lens, you'll catch it using either one of the extremes of background. Good luck.

Comment: Then try taking the filter off.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't mention anything about cleaning? Did you check for dust for instance?
I have had a similar problem where 'something' was attached to the *inside* of the glass which led to artifacts. After a service this has been resolved.

Comment: Only ever cleaned the front and rear optics. I did send my first lens with this problem for service - they said there was a problem with one of the elements and needed replacing at a ridiculous cost. I find it hard to believe that a second one has exactly the same problem. There's nothing obvious on the lens surfaces that I can see.

Comment: @TimB Is it possible that the second lens is also the first lens. I mean if the first one was sold and then the second one purchased, they could be the same lens.

Comment: The first wasn't sold - the repair was too costly, and the company implied it would be scrapped. Anyway the new lens is a different serial number.

Comment: I wouldn't negate the possibility that some manufacturing defect could be present on both the lenses. If they came from the same batch (which you can check with the serial number range) it could even be more likely. You could try to ask your store - or even better: a different one - to try it with a another lens (same type of course). And see what happens. As none of your other lenses have this problem, and the problem exists on different bodies I would still suspect something is wrong with that lens... and don't use the filter (I just noticed). And check the filter as well on another lenses.